# Passing JSON Paramater in URL

Tags: json, url, parameters

I can't seem to pass parameters on the following URL:

This works (API key)

```
https://api.wistia.com/v1/medias.json?api_password=4270cfa9ee6a62203fd09f42bc342125e2187151bff16242df2055a6e4241714
```

This doesn't...

```
https://api.wistia.com/v1/medias.json?api_password=4270cfa9ee6a62203fd09f42bc342125e2187151bff16242df2055a6e4241714?height=360
```

Any help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use '&' instead of second '?'.

Use

```
https://api.wistia.com/v1/medias.json?api_password=4270cfa9ee6a62203fd09f42bc342125e2187151bff16242df2055a6e4241714&height=360
```

Instead of

```
https://api.wistia.com/v1/medias.json?api_password=4270cfa9ee6a62203fd09f42bc342125e2187151bff16242df2055a6e4241714?height=360
```

Comment: While it loads the JSON, it doesn't query/filter the data.

Comment: As per the doc (http://wistia.com/doc/data-api#filtering), filtering supports project_id, name, type and hashed_id.

Comment: Thanks, Tebe. I skipped over that. But it's strange I can only use a '&', and not a '?' between parameters when their docs say to use a '?'. Any idea why that is?

Comment: Its not specific to wistia. Use of '&' to separate the parameters in a url is a query string specification. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string